# Maintaining temp shared memory/storage (a game leaderboard) on just Lambda AWS

Tags: aws-lambda

As described, I have a game with about 10-30 players competing at once. Players submit their scores and receive their ranking every 3 seconds. The returned updates doesn't have to be real-time accurate, but should be correct at the end (after no more writes are done).

Finally, no long-term storage of the data is required, i.e I don't care for the data being discarded once the lambda instance times out.

Can this be achieved only with just lambda function without using other external service?

I'm using Lambda python if that matters.

I used global variables before, but the results were wrong. I know better now, not to use global variables as in-memory database.

Comment: We need more information.  Based on what you're saying - no - you're trying to implement a stateful environment without some sort of permanent backing store.  While you can limit yourself to a single Lambda you can't guarantee that that Lambda will not be restarted.  If that happens then anything in memory is gone.  You really need something like DynamoDB or other backing store to make this work.

Comment: Uh, you are right. I don't care about discarding the whole memory/storage once my lambda timeout. I will update the question accordingly.

Comment: You can influence the lifecycle of a lambda, but at the end of the day, you have no guarantee that any lambda will run for the complete lifespan of a game.  As such, if you want to keep score for the duration of the game, it must be kept somewhere outside of the lambda.